# Why is this an invalid assignment left hand side?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

Why can I do the following operations:

```js
var b1, b2;

b1 = b2 = true;

document.write(b1," ", b2);
document.write("<br>");

b1 = !b2;

document.write(b1," ", b2);
document.write("<br>");

b1 = b2 = !true;

document.write(b1," ", b2);
```

Yet when I try the following operation I recieve a `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side` ?

```js
var b1, b2;

b1 = !b2 = true;

document.write(b1," ", b2);
```

It's obvious that I can't do this, but I can't find an explanation as to why I can't. The [MDN developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_assignment_left-hand_side) for the error states:

> There was an unexpected assignment somewhere. This might be due to a mismatch of a assignment operator and a comparison operator, for example. While a single "=" sign assigns a value to a variable, the "==" or "===" operators compare a value.

All of the assignment operators work individually as proven, so why can't this be combined into a singular operation / chained assignment?

Comment: In actuality, you are trying to do: `var b1, b2; !b2 = true; b1 = b2;` which is obviously wrong. You can't assign an expression to a value...

Comment: b2 is not a  function that check if its true or false you should put it on a parenthesis like your doing a condition chaining reference can be true if they have equal data

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you try to do this:

```
var b1, b2;

b1 = !b2 = true;

document.write(b1, " ", b2);
```

Because they are functionally equivalent<sup>‡</sup> you are basically doing:

```
var b1, b2;

!b2 = true;
b1 = true; //just the value of b2, not b2 itself

document.write(b1, " ", b2);
```

In the line `!b2 = true`, you are trying to assign an expression that evaluates to a value (the left side) to a value - that makes absolutely no sense. Think about it this way:

- `!b2` is being assigned to `true`. `!b2` is an expression and is evaluated to a boolean *value*, not variable.
- This would be analogous to doing `1 + 1 = 2`.  Since `1 + 1` is evaluated to a *value*, you can't assign that to `2`, another value. You must assign a value to *variable*, as value-to-value assignment is semantically and logically invalid.
- Another way to think about the above is to realize this: `1 + 1` is a value. `2` is a value. You cannot assign a value to a value, as that value already has a value. A constant such as `2` has value `2`, it cannot be changed. What if we tried `1 - 1 = 2`? `0`, a constant and value, cannot be `2`, because it is a constant.

Thus, it is semantically and logically invalid to assign a value to a value. You cannot assign `0` to `2` just as you can't assign `false` to `true`.

If you want to understand the syntax and semantics better, and why this throws a `ReferenceError`, you can delve into the [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)<sup>†</sup>. Per the specification:

> [**Section 12.14.1**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors) - **Assignment Operators** - Static Semantics: Early Errors
>
> *`AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression`*
>
> - It is an early [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type) Error if *`LeftHandSideExpression`* is neither an *`ObjectLiteral`* nor an *`ArrayLiteral`* and `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget` of *`LeftHandSideExpression`* is false.

Where `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget` is:

> [**Section 12.14.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget) - **Assignment Operators** - Static Semantics: IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget
>
> ```
> AssignmentExpression :
>   YieldExpression
>   ArrowFunction
>   LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
>   LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
> ```
>
> 1. Return false.

Now look back at your code: `b1 = !b2 = true`. `b1 = !b2` is fine because it is *`LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression`*, thus returning true for `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget`. The problem arises when we check `!b2 = true`. If we look at the definition of *`LeftHandSideExpression`*:

> [**Section 12.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-hand-side-expressions) - **Left-Hand-Side Expressions**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> LeftHandSideExpression :
>   NewExpression
>   CallExpression
> ```

(You can view the definitions of *`NewExpression`* and *`CallExpression`* in the specification link above)

You can see that `!b2 = true` is not a valid *`AssignmentExpression`*, as it does not fit the criteria *`LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression`*. This is because `!b2` is not a valid *`LeftHandSideExpression`*, also not an *`ObjectLiteral`* nor *`ArrayLiteral`*, thus `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget` returns false, throwing the `ReferenceError`. Note that the error is an [*early* error](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-error-handling-and-language-extensions), meaning it is thrown before any code is executed, as noted in [@Bergi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581507/why-is-this-an-invalid-assignment-left-hand-side/40581558#comment68417400_40581558).

---

You can combat this by doing either of the following, depending on your desired outcome:

```
b1 = !(b2 = true);
```

With parentheses, inside the parentheses takes precedence over outside. That way, `b2` is assigned, and since it is `true`, inside the parentheses evaluates to `true`. Next, it's equivalent to:

```
b1 = !(true);
```

As inside the parentheses is evaluated to `true` as mentioned above. `b1` will be the opposite of `b2` as expected, and `b2` will be `true`.

If you wanted `b1` to be `true` and `b2` to be `false`, restructure the statement like this:

```
b2 = !(b1 = true);
```

This way, it's the exact opposite of the above, giving `b1 = true`, and `b2 = false`.

---

<sup><sup>‡</sup>As @Bergi mentioned in the comments, `b1` is assigned the right operand, `true` in this case, not `!b2`.</sup>

<sup><sup>†</sup>Although most browsers currently do not support all features of ECMAScript 6 (2015), and instead use [ECMAScript 5.1 (2011)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), the specification is the same for both versions. All definitions are the same, and thus the explanation is still valid.</sup>

Comment: On the other hand I think the OP's intention was to make b1 true and b2 false

Comment: @DavidTheWin are you sure? `b1 = !b2 = true` seems as if they want `!b2` to be false, which means `b2` should be true and `b1` be false.

Comment: I read it as "b1 and !b2 are both true" with b2 therefore being false

Comment: @DavidTheWin Hmm, that's the problem with this kind of 'chained assignment' - it can have two different results. I'll add that into the answer, thanks!

Comment: Actually it is `b1 = true;` not `b1 = b2;`. The result of the assignment operation simply is the right operand, not getting the left hand side evaluated. It does not matter for a plain lexical variable, but can for more complex assignment targets.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I mentioned they were functionally equivalent in this situation. I will edit accordingly, thanks!

Comment: @Bergi in my answer, you were right, but here, `!b2 = true;` is not a valid assignment, so `b1 = undefined;`. In fact, `b1` never gets assigned anything in this case because of the error.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Given it's a syntax error, none of this is executed at all of course, but if it would we'd still get the `true` value from the right hand side instead of `!b2`.

Comment: @DavidTheWin The original intention was to make b1 false and b2 true. The example is currently correct.

Comment: @AndrewLi Where you have **Using parentheses, inside the parentheses** - I'm confused, is **Using parentheses** meant to be a heading here? At the moment it reads that you have parentheses inside parentheses. It's just a bit confusing to read at the moment - in my opinion.

Comment: @Zze Sorry, it was a bit unclear. I meant: *With parentheses, the inside expressions take precedence over the outside ones*

Answer (score 27):

```
b1 = b2 = true;
```

is equivalent to

```
b2 = true;
b1 = true;
```

An **assignment returns the right operand**. It's easy to see within an interactive console (like [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/), [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/), [jsc](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JSC)). See the [spec details in Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40581550/1218980).

[image: node interactive console assignement return value example]

And when you try `b1 = !b2 = true;`, the equivalent makes no sense:

```
(!b2) = true; // true = true; causes the error.
b1 = b2;      // never evaluated.
```

This is because the **`!` takes [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) on the `=` assignment operator** as demonstrated by the parentheses in `(!b2)`.

The order goes:

1. `b2` is `undefined` since it was not initialized yet.
2. Then `!b2 === true` as `!undefined === true`, so `!b2` becomes `true`,
3. and then the assignment occurs, so `true = true`.

You can make it work as you expect by adding parentheses:

```
b1 = !(b2 = true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially the reference to the precedence. I don't understand: `!b2 = true; // true = true;` why is it `true = true` when I am yet to assign `b2`?

Comment: @Zze because `b2 === undefined` at first. Then `!b2 === true` as `!undefined === true`, so `!b2` becomes `true`, and then the assignment occurs, so `true = true`.

Comment: Actually it is `b1 = true;` not `b1 = b2;`. The result of the assignment operation simply is the right operand, not getting the left hand side evaluated. It does not matter for a plain lexical variable, but can for more complex assignment targets.

Comment: @Bergi Consider this example: `var b1, b2; b1 = b2 = []`, as your comment it seems that the `b1` and `b2` should refer to different arrays, but they refer to the same array, so I think `b1 = b2` is correct. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dashtinejad No, I never said that the right operand is re-evaluated. My point is just that `b2` is never used to provide the value, it's only a target of an assignment. What happens actually is more like `{ const temp []; b2 = temp; b1 = temp; }`.

Answer (score 10):

Th expression `b1 = !b2 = true;` gets evaluated from right to left

First : `!b2 = true`

then : `b1 = <result of previous assignment>`

`!b2 = true` doesn't make logical sense and hence the error.

If you write `b1 = b2 = true;`, it won't give any such error

Comment: The expression is never evaluated at all, because it is syntactically invalid and throws an early error on parsing.

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention the AST **Assigning to rvalue** ([1](https://astexplorer.net/#/5eAU2itaBf/1)) ([2](https://astexplorer.net/#/5eAU2itaBf/2))

```js
if (1 + 1 = 2)
 console.log("1 + 1 = 2");
```

```js
var b1, b2;
b1 = !b2 = true;
```

to confirm the *expression is never evaluated*.