# Why does this ReferenceError prevent all execution when this TypeError does not?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, typeerror, referenceerror

While reading a [PluralSight Tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=javascript-programming-basics&author=kyle-simpson&name=javascript-programming-basics-m1&clip=7&mode=live), it was claimed that a syntax error would prevent previous lines from being executed. `2();` and `2 = 3;` were both given as examples.

But upon testing this behavior in Chrome's Console, only `2 = 3;` prevented previous lines from executing.

Here's the output for `2();` (I'm using <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd>):

```
console.log("foo 1");
2();
console.log("foo 2");
VM224:1 foo 1
VM224:2 Uncaught TypeError: 2 is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:2
```

And here is for `2 = 3;`

```
console.log("foo 1");
2 = 3;
console.log("foo 2");
VM202:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

As you can see, the first line is executed for `2();` and `foo 1` is printed out. But for `2 = 3;`, nothing is printed.

So why is one type of error preventing printing and execution of prior code, but the other doesn't, and is this browser-dependent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the nature of the `ReferenceError`. Per [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40581550/5647260):

If you want to understand the syntax and semantics better, and why this throws a ReferenceError, you can delve into the [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). Per the specification:

> **[Section 12.14.1 - Assignment Operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors)** - Static Semantics: Early Errors
>
> *`AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression`*
>
> **It is an early Reference Error** if *`LeftHandSideExpression`* is neither an *`ObjectLiteral`* nor an *`ArrayLiteral`* and *`IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget`* of *`LeftHandSideExpression`* is false.

Where `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget` is:

> **[Section 12.14.3 - Assignment Operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget)** - Static Semantics: IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget
>
> ```
> AssignmentExpression :
>   YieldExpression
>   ArrowFunction
>   LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
>   LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
> ```
>
> 1. Return false.

As you can see, an "early error" is raised if the assignment complies with the definition of *`AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression`* but *`LeftHandSideExpression`* is invalid. Since `2` is not an *`ObjectLiteral`*, *`ArrayLiteral`*, and `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget` returns false, the assignment fails and the `ReferenceError` is thrown.

Now, to define the term "early error". Per the specification:

> **[Section 16 - Errors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-16)**
>
> [...] An *early error* is an error that can be detected and reported prior to the evaluation of any construct in the [*`Program`*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14) containing the error.

That means none of the code is executed when an early error is raised. Because in your assignment, an early `ReferenceError` is raised, none of the code is executed, and thus, the console is never logged to.

In the second example, a [function call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3) is performed. Step 5 of evaluation throws a `TypeError` because the result of [`IsCallable(func)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.11) is false (as `func` is a `Number`), and the `TypeError` is thrown. Note that the `TypeError` is **not** an early error. Thus, execution of code does happen, and the console is logged to. When the line `2();` is encountered, it is evaluated and the `TypeError` is thrown.

This is *not* browser-dependent because all browsers and JavaScript engines must follow the specification. It should be noted that this was taken from the ECMAScript® *2015* (AKA ES6) Specification, which has not been fully implemented on all engines. I recommend taking a look in the [ECMAScript® 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) (ES5) Specification, in which all modern engines implement fully, though definitions of the above have not changed between both version.

---

It should be noted that these are not syntax errors. `2();` is a `TypeError` because the `Number` type is not callable. `2 = 3` is a `ReferenceError` because `2` is an invalid left hand side to be assigned to. Assigning a function to a name that is a numeral is, however, a syntax error. It violates the syntax of a [function declaration](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) to do `function 2() {}`, as the declaration expects an [identifier](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) as a name.

A numeral is a *constant*, you cannot assign a constant to anything because it is constant. `2 = 3` makes no sense in the real world, and is thus prevented in the specification. Similarly, you cannot do `var 2 = function() {}`.