# Why is this an invalid assignment left hand side? - 2.0

Tags: javascript

The reason why this is **2.0** is because a few months ago I posted this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581507/why-is-this-an-invalid-assignment-left-hand-side) in relation to bools. Trying to understand why `b1 = !b2 = true;` was erroring. I learnt about *functional equivancy* and *right-to-left* evaluation order.

Now this morning, I was fiddling with something and I am confused as to why the following code is throwing a similar error.

```js
function test (){
  return 1;
}

console.log((test())++);
```

I looked up [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for javascript, but it says... (number is precedence)

> **20** Grouping
>   
> **18**  Function Call
>   
> **17**  Postfix Increment
>   
> **17** Postfix Decrement

So why does this throw an error?

Comment: Same reason as was explained. Think of a postfix increment like `a++` to be the equivalent of `a = a + 1`. Now apply the answer to your previous question to your code, namely `test() = test() + 1;`.

Comment: Or piggybacking on @MikeMcCaughan comment, `1 = 1 + 1`. Doesn't make sense does it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this an invalid assignment left hand side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581507/why-is-this-an-invalid-assignment-left-hand-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `++` operator adds one to a variable's value and assigns the result to the variable. In other words, `foo++` is approximately* equivalent to `foo = foo + 1`. Now consider your code:

```
(test())++
```

`test()` evaluates to `1`, so you basically have this:

```
(1)++
```

Or:

```
(1) = 1 + 1
```

The left-hand side, `(1)`, doesn't make any sense. You can't assign a value to a number, hence the error.

*In fact, the expression `foo = foo + 1` evaluates to the value of `foo` *after* the addition, whereas `foo++` evaluates to the value of `foo` *before* the addition. `foo++`, then, is actually equivalent to `(oldFoo = foo, foo = foo + 1, oldFoo)`.